# Android intent to call a contact, not a number

Tags: android, android-intent

**Context:**

- I wrote a small easy dialer for android which dials telephone numbers
  for contacts.
- I use Intent.ACTION_CALL and pass in "tel:" for contacts with just one tel number or with a preferred default number
- Within the app I have the contact's lookup_key so that I can access the contact

**Question:**

I want to initiate a call to a *Contact* not to a *number* so that Android:

- if contact has 2+ numbers: will fire up a phone number selection dialog and then initiate the call
- if the contact has just 1 number: just initiate the call

I could of course implement a popup from scratch but I'd prefer to delegate to a standard action so that the user has the very same UX as using the standard dialer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to prompt the user to choose the contact, then which phone number to call (if there is more than one)... than pass that to the intent to make the call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
    Uri contactData = data.getData();                   
    String theID = contactData.toString());

    //MAKE YOUR CALL .. do whatever... example:
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri contactData = Uri.parse(theID);
    Cursor cur = contentResolver.query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
    String theNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("data4"));
    cur.close();

    Intent my_callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    my_callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    my_callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + theNumber));
    startActivity(my_callIntent);


    }                   

}
```

Its not pretty or perfect, probably needs some modifications, just kinda going off the top of my head but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, this is not exactly what I was searching for but still a step in the right direction. This way I can pick a contact but the 'cur' object might still hold references to more that a single number if the owner has

Comment: Starting that particular intent should display all contacts (that have phone numbers) and if the user chooses a contact that has more than one number, it will automatically prompt to select which number... that should be the only item in the cursor.  If that wasn't what you were looking for, apologies for misunderstanding.